# Meteor templates loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor

I've build a simple app with Meteor. It basicly gets locations from database and shows them to user. This is done via webservice. In the template I have a google map. Which gets the coordinates of locations and then displays them on the map. The basic idea works. However, the problem is that my webservice is called when google map loads. Therefore when template map is created (it's created when user selects tab /map and map template is created - or am I wrong?). And because of that when I open my homepage first, the webservice is not called and I don't get the data.

How is this problem solved? I want to load all the data when user opens the app. onRendered and onCreated won't solve this I think. If you know the answer please write it down, if it is obvious please share a link where I can read about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you should first create the map (without marker), and when you have the geolocalisation of the user, you will be able to draw it on the map. Or you can wait the user position before rendering the map. All you need is a reactive treatment.

You can store a variable in a ReactiveVar - you just need to add this very interesting package :

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

or you can use the meteor Session. I will use the session for the example, it's easier.

Your `template.js` (that I wrote without testing, comment on this post if you have any issue)

```
Template.map.onRendered(function() {
     // Create an undefined value for this template, 
     this.marker;
     var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

     // Render an empty map
     this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
     });
     // Each time a reactive variable like ReactiveVar or session is edited,
     // rerun this function
     this.autorun(function() {
        // this autorun will rerun each time Session.get("userPosition") is edited
        var userPosition = Session.get("userPosition");
        if (userPosition && this.marker === undefined) {
            this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: myLatLng,
               map: this.map, 
               title: 'Hello user!'
            });
         }
     });
});
```

Source google map API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: This is what I have looked up to. But my problem is a little bit different. my map template is loaded when user gets to www.mymeteor.com/map (look /map, other is example). Only then the map is loaded because this is called Template.map.onCreated. But when the user gets to my page he won't go to /map, he will go to /. And when he gets to /, map.onCreated will not be called, because it is not created until the user visits /map. How can I make it load on the start? That's the question

Comment: if you want to display the map when the user visits /, you just need to add the template inside the template of / : `{{ > map}}`. If you want data of the map before rendering it, you need to subscribe to map data ...